# Prove that $S^1$ is a manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

The question is as follows:

The circle $S^1$ is defined by $\mathbb R$/$\mathbb Z$, where $\mathbb Z$ is viewed as an additive subgroup of $\mathbb R$ and where $\mathbb R$ acts on itself by addition. Prove that $S^1$ is a manifold. Prove that if $X$ is a connected,  compact, one–dimensional manifold, then $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

I only have a very basic understanding of manifolds and am struggling on how to approach this problem. If it is possible to explain the logic/rational behind the steps in the proof that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The classification of all compact connected one-dimensional manifolds is a relative simple result, opposed to the classification of all Surfaces, which is a far more involved result. One way to prove it is to first prove that every compact connect 1d manifold is homeomorphic to a graph, and then prove that each graph is homeomorphic to $S^1$. There are some details to fill in here, but I guess that it is intuitively clear. For the details, you might want consult to

http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~meier007/ClassificationSurfaces

Comment: This seems a little ambitious for a first look at manifolds

Comment: Nevertheless very cool!:)

Answer (score 1):

Showing that $S^1$ is a manifold requires showing that it is Hausdorff (which is okay because $\Bbb Z$ is discrete in $\Bbb R$), second-countable (which is okay because $\Bbb R$ is second-countable and the orbits under $\mathbb Z$ are discrete, so projection is a local homeomorphism), and locally euclidean (again, because projection is a local homeomorphism).

The more interesting part is to show that all connected compact $1$-manifolds are homeomorphic, but I cannot do this in an answer here, maybe you should check out the classification of $1$-manifolds in Milnor's *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint*. The basic idea is as follows: Cover the connected compact $1$-manifold $M$ by two connected charts whose intersection is disconnected. Then their pre-image in $\mathbb R$, arranged in a nice way, must "wrap up", so some points will be identified. Iterating this, we get that $M$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R/ \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you clarify why these conclusions follow? Especially why exactly it follows that $S^1$ is second-countable.

Comment: Well, the image of a basis under a local homeomirphism is in fact a basis  of the target space.

Comment: And the local homeomorphism is the projection map?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Can you give an alternate explanation as to why it follows that the projections are a local homeomorphism? I have yet to encounter orbits.

Comment: The projection is injective on open balls of radius less than 1. Then use that the projection map is continuous and open, so it is a homeomorphism onto its image.